# Mysql query in php of webserver

Tags: php, mysql

This is the php java script to run on webserver. In it i will get input from android app the query is

```
<?php
$mysqlDebug = true;

//create connection

print "hello 1";

mysql_connect("localhost", "pu", "Ind");

print "hello 2";

mysql_select_db("leengage");

print "hello 3";
print mysql_error();
// Check connection

if (mysql_error())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
    print "hello 4";
}

print "hello 5";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO details_master(name ,phone, email, birthdaydate, birthdaymonth, anniversarydate, anniversarymonth,created)
VALUES ('Peterr', 'Griffinn','hello@hello.com',12,12,12,12,'0000-00-00 00:00:00')");

print mysql_error();

// escape variables for security

print "hello 7";

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$birthdaydate = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['birthdaydate']);
$birthdaymonth = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['birthdaymonth']);
$anniversarydate = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['anniversarydate']);
$anniversarymonth = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['anniversarymonth']);
$created = mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['created']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO details_master(name ,phone, email, birthdaydate, birthdaymonth, 
anniversarydate, anniversarymonth,created)
VALUES ('$name','$phone', '$email', '$birthdaydate', '$birthdaymonth', '$anniversarydate', 
'$anniversarymonth', '$created')";

print "hello 8";

if (!mysql_query($conn, $sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error($conn));
}

echo "1 record added";
?>
```

The first insert query is running fine and inserting records from app but second insert query is not working it gives following errors.

> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 24
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 25
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 26
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 27
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 28
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 29
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 30
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 31
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home on line 37
>
> [01-Aug-2014 05:44:53 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home on line 38

Just in case I am getting input from android app and code i am using for this is on create:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

And on button click is:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// define the parameter
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone",phone));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthdaydate",s1));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthdaymonth",s2));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("anniversarydate",s3));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("anniversarymonth",s4));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created",formattedDate));

String response = null;

try {
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://purplefront.net/PurpleEngage/mydatainsert.php", postParameters);
    
    // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
    String result = response.toString();  

    //parse json data
    Log.d("result data", result);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
}
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated, and will likely be removed in the next PHP version. Use the `mysqli` or the `PDO` extensions instead.

Answer (score -1):

You keep referencing `$conn`, which doesn't appear to be set anywhere. It looks like you're trying to use `mysqli_` syntax (connection object, then sql) with `mysql_` functions (which use the last opened connection)

This answer assumes you convert all your calls to `mysqli_` (you can't mix and match) but this should point you in the right direction

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","pu","Ind");
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why? [mysql_ is deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: web server i am using supports only mysql not mysqli

Comment: just in case i am getting input from android and code i am using is this is on create  > StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new >StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

>StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: Suggestion: change your webserver!

Comment: it is of company webserver where it is my test so i am stuck with it.

Comment: @Manish what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: actully script is running on webserver